# receiving data from 1st error but not subsequent ones in Subject

Tags: rxjs, angular6

I am facing a peculiar issue. My `component` subscribes to a `Subject`. I receive data from the associated `observable` when first `error` is called but not from the subsequent ones. I have not unsubscribed.

I sign up with details of an existing user. I get error the first time (right behaviour). Then I again click sign up button to send the same request but this time the component doesn't receive the message from `error`.

Interestingly, if I use `next` instead of `error` then the code works ok. Does `observable` stops working if `error` is called ?

The code snippets

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.userSignupSubscription = this.subscribeToSignupAttempt();
    this.createForm();
  }
subscribeToSignupAttempt() {
    return this.userManagementService.userSignUpState$.subscribe(
      (res: Result) => { console.log('signup response ',res);this.handleSignupResponse(res); },
      (error: Result) => { console.log('signup error response ',error);this.handleSignupErrorResponse(error); },
    );
  }
```

the backend service sending data is

```
@Injectable()
export class UserManagementService{
...
private signUpStateSubject: Subject<Result>;
public userSignUpState$: Observable<Result>; // naming convention for Streams has $ in the end.

constructor(){
this.signUpStateSubject = new Subject<Result>();
this.userSignUpState$ = this.signUpStateSubject.asObservable();
}

addUser(){
...
      (error: ServerResponseAPI) => { //This code send the message.
         console.log("got error from the Observable: ",error);
        const errorMessage: string = this.helper.userFriendlyErrorMessage(error);
        this.signUpStateSubject.error(new Result(errorMessage, error['additional-info'])); //change this to .next and the code works
      }
}
```

see the pic below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I should use `next` instead of `error` because it is how `rxjs` works. It is the contract of rxjs. `error` means that the stream is not operational anymore and new one would need to be opened.